# Как будет время правильно "с солью" или "с соли"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, разговорная-речь

Прочитал сегодня на упаковке продукта надпись *с соли*. Правильно ли было написано?

Как мне кажется, было бы правильно написать *с солью*.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В большинстве словарей фиксируется такое название кисломолочного продукта: [сузьма](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_culinary/2070/%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B0).
В некоторых — [сюзьма](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/vasmer/48482/%D1%81%D1%8E%D0%B7%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B0).
При приготовлении могут добавляться травы, специи, соль, фрукты, мёд ([сюзьма с укропом](https://market.yandex.ru/product--dva-kazaka-siuzma-s-ukropom-6-5-500-g/607547002)).

Дело, конечно, не во времени, а в правильном выборе падежа. На упаковке нужно было написать или ***с солью*** (с чем? Т. п.), или ***с добавлением соли*** (чего? Р. п.).
Трудно сказать, по какой причине первое слово исчезло. Сейчас в бывших союзных республиках за этикетками и надписями на упаковках особо смотреть некому.

[Сузьма (сюзьма)](https://hi-chef.ru/product/suzma/)